# "Import in body of module; reorder to top import/first" Across Many Files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I have the same error as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49688260/import-in-body-of-module-reorder-to-top-import-first-eslint-reactjs), except instead of it just occurring in one file it is occurring in many; once I fix it for one file, another just pops up with the same error. I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600727/create-react-app-failed-to-compile-import-first-error) but whenever I run `react-scripts start` a node_modules folder is created in my src, so that solution isn't viable.

It would be too time consuming to have to fix every file that has this error every time I compile, so how can I get rid of this error? It seems to just be an eslint issue.

Comment: you can try `eslint --fix` from the command line

Comment: I had to do `eslint --fix node_modules` but thank you that fixed it, feel free to make an answer and I can mark it as accepted

Comment: you should never tinker files inside node_modules. I was suggesting `eslint --fix /path/to/problem/folder`, but i did not know node_modules was the problem folder. Instead you should add node_modules to eslint ignore list

Comment: add a file called .eslintignore at your root and add node_modules as the content in that file

Comment: Find a solution here:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600727/create-react-app-failed-to-compile-import-first-error/56109274#56109274

Comment: when this happened and tried everything, my code was so simple that there couldn't be any problem, I just had to restart my code editor and then it worked

Answer (score 109):

you will get this error if you declare `variable` in between your imports,

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const URL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE;

import demoXLXSFile from '../../assets/others/Demo.xlsx';
import './student.list.styles.scss';
```

declare `variables` after importing everything,

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import demoXLXSFile from '../../assets/others/Demo.xlsx';
import './student.list.styles.scss';

const URL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE;
```

Comment: I had a similar issue using imports from '@material-ui/core' and '@material-ui/icons'.  I didn't have a variable separating my imports but had to rearrange my imports for the file to compile properly.  Specifically, the import PersonAddDisabledOutlined from '@material-ui/icons/PersonAddDisabledOutlined' would throw off all imports below it.

Answer (score 23):

I found this issue while I was using `React.lazy` in my existing project. I got this error `Failed to compile.` :- `Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first` (with create-react-app).

```
import React from 'react';
import SelectField from '../inputs/SelectField';
const Questions = React.lazy(() => import('./questions'))
import _ from 'lodash';
```

Solution:-

Only reorder the position i.e. put all import on top then react.lazy.

```
import React from 'react';
import SelectField from '../inputs/SelectField';
import _ from 'lodash';
const Questions = React.lazy(() => import('./questions'))
```

Comment: Thanks, now it seems so obvious. React lazy is not an import statement but regular code

Answer (score 14):

I got this same error when I added an extra semicolon ';' at the end of an import statement.

I suggest removing any extraneous semicolons. This should make the error go away.

Comment: Man True Story :D

Answer (score 5):

Moving every import statement to the top of the file solves the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Happened to me when I put require before import like this:

```
require('dotenv').config()
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
...
```

Solution: Put the require after the imports

Answer (score 4):

If You are using Component Lazy loading then always put lazy load component import code below normal import code.

Correct Example

```
import First from './first'
const Second = React.lazy(()=>import("./Second))
```

Incorrect Example

```
const Second = React.lazy(()=>import("./Second))
import First from './first'
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue too. I found that you must import all ES6 modules at the top level of your JavaScript files."... the structure of ES6 modules is static, you can’t conditionally import or export things. That brings a variety of benefits.

This restriction is enforced syntactically by **only allowing imports and exports at the top level of a module**:"
From Dr. Axel Rauschmayer’s [Exploring JS](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_basics-of-es6-modules):

Comment: Find more details here:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600727/create-react-app-failed-to-compile-import-first-error/56109274#56109274

Answer (score 2):

Wrong
1.

```
import React ,{useState ,useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Post from './Post';
import db from "./firebase"
```

---

Right
2.

```
import React ,{useState ,useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Post from './Post';
import db from "./firebase.js"
```

---

//this is code firebase.js

```
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const storage = firebase.storage();

export default {db,auth,storage};
```

---

When I change the firebase into firebase.js in Snippet 2.
My Error vanished

Answer (score 1):

I had forgotten to add from.

Before:

```
import UpperBlock;
```

After:

```
import UpperBlock from "../components/dashboard/shared/UpperBlock";
```

Make sure you import well your component and then stop the server and restart it again. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're experiencing this error in modern versions of react(current version 18.0.0) make sure you're making all your imports before the ReactDOM.createRoot declaration.

For example, I got the error with:

```
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
import { Provider } from "./context";
```

This will result in an error. Instead, import everything before the createRoot:

```
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { Provider } from "./context";
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
```

This will fix the error. Simple fix but it's easy to miss

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add {Component} after importing 'react' library to my project, this solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Move all** of your `import`s to the **top of the file**.
Even in case of a `require` *(that is written in between import statements)*, this error will come.

e.g.

```
import 'some_module';
require('some_file');
import 'some_other_module');
```

This would result in an error.

You would want to do this instead:

```
import 'some_module';
import 'some_other_module');
require('some_file');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue when I installed chat.js library in my reactJs project. I solved this issue by moving my chart.Js import to the index.js file

**index.js file:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Chart as ChartJS, ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend } from "chart.js"; <--- imported
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

ChartJS.register(ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend);  <---- imported
```

Answer (score 0):

If I put double Semicolon behind the importing statement than I got "[error"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1Xpn.png).[you can see difference between two pictures in import './index.css'; is different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EGoP.png)

For Example :-

```html
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';;
import 'tachyons';
import {robots} from "./Robots";
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import CardList from './CardList';
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31682449)